# Run / execute a section of a notebook in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode notebooks, you can add markdown headers to divide your notebook into sections which can be collapsed / folded. Is there a way to execute all cells within such collapsed section, without unfolding it and running all the cells manually one by one?

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131118) in the vscode repo describing precisely this and it's marked as completed, so the functionality *should* be there. However, using the usual `Shift+Enter` or `Ctrl+Enter` on a markdown header does not run anything in vscode 1.68.1. I also cannot see it mentioned in the docs anywhere and the issue is locked, so one cannot ask there.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174745